# The requested resource / was not found on this server using only Dockerfile but not with docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, http-status-code-404

I don't remember what I was trying to test but I always got the following message when I tried to access the root of my server (index.php) : `The requested resource / was not found on this server.`

So after several attempts, I managed to access it using docker-compose but not with only a Dockerfile.

I'm trying to understand why.

**Dockerfile attempt (not working)**

```
|--- Dockerfile
|--- index.php
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.1-alpine
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Docker commands :

```
docker build -t docker_dockerfile_php .
docker run -p 8002:8000 docker_dockerfile_php
```

Now when I try to access `localhost:8002`, I have the following message : `The requested resource / was not found on this server.`

**Docker compose attempt (working)**

```
|--- docker
     |--- php
          |--- Dockerfile
|--- docker-compose.yml
|--- index.php
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

My docker-compose.yml :

```
services:
  php:
    image: docker_compose_php
    build: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/myapp
```

Docker commands :

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Now when I try to access `localhost:8001`, I can acces my index.php file.

With the Docker compose attempt, I can use Xdebug on VSC with .devcontainer.

If anyone can enlighten me, I would be grateful.

Comment: In your second example you set `WORKDIR`; is that a necessary step?  In general I'd prefer `COPY`ing your application code into an image to injecting it with `volumes:`, given the choice.

Comment: In my second example, if I use `COPY` instead of `WORKDIR`, it doesn't work. I get the message `The requested resource / was not found on this server`. In the first one neither `copy` nor `workdir` works.

Comment: Those two directives do very different things.  Do you need both?  (Frequently, specify `WORKDIR` first, so that you can then `COPY some-host-file .` into that directory without repeating its path.)

Comment: I don't use both in the same time. In the first attempt, I use `COPY` and in the seconde `WORKDIR`.  My question is  not probably enough evident, is it? Should I edit it? I understand the two directives are differente. Do you know a documentation (or tutorial) who explain with example the difference (and add, env, etc.). The basis...

Comment: Are you looking for the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) in the Docker documentation?

Comment: Of course! It's my starting point.

Comment: I'll have a look at the official document again. However, I still don't understand why the second case (compose) works and not the first (dockfile). For now, I need to sleep (26 is too much). I need to focus on one project. Thanks for highlighting the difference between copy and workdir.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the first attempt work, I set the working directory with `WORKDIR`. So I modified my dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:8.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .
CMD [ "php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

The seconde attempt's advantage, the one with compose file, allow me to add files while the container is running.